# SQL Error Msg 142, Level 15, State 2, Line 0 Incorrect syntax for definition of the 'TABLE' constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting this error

> Msg 142, Level 15, State 2, Line 0
>   Incorrect syntax for definition of the 'TABLE' constraint.

I can't figure it out and i am running out of time... just use top half of SQL I still have to edit the rest, but I need this error solved... or information on what I am doing wrong... I am also  having issues determining NULL and not null

```
Create table Service
(
    ServiceCode varchar(15) not null
        constraint PK_Service primary key clustered,
    Description varchar(100) not null,
    CostPerHour smallmoney not null
)


create table SupplyCategory
(
    SupplyCategoryCode varchar(5) not null
        constraint PK_SupplyCategory primary key clustered,
    Description varchar(100)not null,
    StorageRoom varchar(5)not null
)

create table Supply
(
    SupplyCode varchar(8)not null
        constraint PK_Supply primary key clustered,
    Description varchar(100)not null,
    SupplyCategoryCode varchar(5) not null
        constraint FK_SupplyToSupplyCategory references SupplyCategory(SupplyCategoryCode)
)

create table StaffType
(
    StaffTypeCode int identity(1,1)not null
        constraint PK_StaffType primary key clustered,
    Description varchar(100)not null,
    Wage smallmoney not null
        constraint CK_Wage check(Wage >=0)
        constraint DF_Wage default 20
)

create table Staff
(
    StaffID int not null
        constraint PK_Staff primary key clustered,
    FirstName varchar(50) not null,
    LastName varchar(50) not null,
    TrainingCredits smallint not null,
    StaffTypeCode int not null
        constraint FK_StaffToStaffType references StaffType(StaffTypecode)
)

create table Client
(
    ClientID int identity(1,1) not null
        constraint PK_Client primary key clustered,
    FirstName varchar(50) not null,
    LastName varchar(50) not null,
    Phone varchar(14) null
        constraint CK_Phone check(Phone like '([0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]')
)

create table Job
(
    JobNumber int identity(1,1) not null
        constraint PK_Job primary key clustered,
    Date datetime not null,
    Address varchar(100) not null,
    City varchar(50) not null,
    Province char(2) not null
        constraint CK_Province check(Province like '[^A-Z][^A-Z]'),
    PostalCode char(7) null
        constraint CK_PostalCode Check(PostalCode like '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]'),
    SubTotal money not null,
    GST money not null,
    Total money not null
        constraint CK_TotalRecivedMustBeAfterSubTotal check(Total > SubTotal),

    ClientID int not null
        constraint FK_JobToClient references Client(ClientID),
    StaffID int not null
        constraint FK_JobToStaff references Staff(StaffID)
) 

create table JobService
(
    JobNumber int not null
        constraint FK_JobServiceToJob references Job(JobNumber),
    ServiceCode varchar(15) not null
        constraint FK_JobServiceToService references Service(ServiceCode),
    Notes varchar(200) not null,
    Hours int not null,
    ActualCostPerHour smallmoney not null,
    ExtCost smallmoney not null,
    constraint PK_JobService primary key clustered (JobNumber,ServiceCode)
)

create table Training 
(
    TrainingID varchar(20) not null
        constraint PK_Training primary key clustered,
    Description varchar(100) not null,
    Credits tinyint 
        constraint CK_Credits check(Credits <=6)
        constraint DF_Credits default 3
)

create table StaffTraining
(
    StaffID int not null
        constraint FK_StaffTrainingToStaff references Staff(StaffID),
    TrainingID varchar(20) not null
        constraint FK_StaffTrainingToTraining references Training(TrainingID),      
        CompletionDate datetime not null,
    constraint PK_StaffTraining primary key clustered(StaffID,TrainingID)
)

create table JobSupply
(
    JobNumber int not null
        constraint FK_JobSupplyToJob references Job(JobNumber),
    SupplyCode varchar(8) not null
        constraint FK_JobSupplyToSupply references Supply(SupplyCode),
    Quantity smallint not null,
    constraint PK_JobSupply primary key clustered (JobNumber,SupplyCode)
)

Delete JobService
Delete Service
Delete JobSupply
Delete Supply
Delete SupplyCategory
Delete Job
Delete Client
Delete StaffTraining
Delete Training
Delete Staff
Delete StaffType


Alter table Client 
Add Email varchar(300) 
    constraint ck_Email check(Email like '%@%.%') 

Alter table Staff
Add Available char(1) null
            default 'Y'
                constraint CK_Available check(Available in ('Y','N'))

Alter table job
Add constraint DF_Province default 'AB'

CREATE nonclustered INDEX IX_JobNumber
        ON JobService (JobNumber)

CREATE nonclustered INDEX IX_ServiceCode
        ON JobService (ServiceCode)

CREATE nonclustered INDEX IX_ClientId
        ON Job (ClientID)

CREATE nonclustered INDEX IX_StaffID
        ON Job (StaffID)

CREATE nonclustered INDEX IX_JobNumber
        ON JobSupply (JobNumber)

CREATE nonclustered INDEX IX_SupplyCode
        ON JobSupply (SupplyCode)

CREATE nonclustered INDEX IX_SupplyCategoryCode
        ON Supply (SupplyCategoryCode)

CREATE nonclustered INDEX IX_StaffTypeCode
        ON Staff (StaffTypeCode)

CREATE nonclustered INDEX IX_StaffID
        ON StaffTraining (StaffID)

CREATE nonclustered INDEX IX_TrainingID
        ON StaffTraining (TrainingID)

Insert into StaffType (Description,Wage)
values ('Painter',25)
Insert into StaffType (Description,Wage)
values ('Sander',20)
Insert into StaffType (Description,Wage)
values ('Builder',30)
Insert into StaffType (Description,Wage)
values ('Demolition',35)
Insert into StaffType (Description,Wage)
values ('Cleaning',15)


Insert into Staff (StaffID,FirstName,LastName,TrainingCredits,StaffTypeCode)
values (11111,'Jason','Painter',12,1)
Insert into Staff (StaffID,FirstName,LastName,TrainingCredits,StaffTypeCode)
values (22222,'Suzy','Cleaner',12,5)
Insert into Staff (StaffID,FirstName,LastName,TrainingCredits,StaffTypeCode)
values (33333,'Alex','Boom',13,4)
Insert into Staff (StaffID,FirstName,LastName,TrainingCredits,StaffTypeCode)
values (44444,'Adam','Scraper',15,2)
Insert into Staff (StaffID,FirstName,LastName,TrainingCredits,StaffTypeCode)
values (55555,'Bob','LaBuilder',21,3)

Insert into Training (TrainingID, Description, Credits)
values ('Paint101','Introduction to Painting',3)
Insert into Training (TrainingID, Description, Credits)
values ('Finishing123','Sanding and Finishing',6)
Insert into Training (TrainingID, Description, Credits)
values ('Cleaning224','Cleaning and Clearing',3)
Insert into Training (TrainingID, Description, Credits)
values ('Demolition101','Making Things go Boom!',4)
Insert into Training (TrainingID, Description, Credits)
values ('Safety104','Basic Safety Protocols',3)
Insert into Training (TrainingID, Description, Credits)
values ('Repairs105','Basic Repairs',3)
Insert into Training (TrainingID, Description, Credits)
values ('ClientConflict202','Dealing with Grumpy Clients',6)
Insert into Training (TrainingID, Description, Credits)
values ('Building321','Basic Building Concepts',6)


Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (11111,'Paint101','Jan 1 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (11111,'Safety104','Jan 4 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (11111,'ClientConflict202','Jan 7 2016')

Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (22222,'Cleaning224','Jan 1 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (22222,'Safety104','Jan 4 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (22222,'ClientConflict202','Jan 7 2016')

Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (33333,'Demolition101','Jan 1 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (33333,'Safety104','Jan 4 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (33333,'ClientConflict202','Jan 7 2016')

Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (44444,'Finishing123','Jan 1 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (44444,'Safety104','Jan 4 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (44444,'ClientConflict202','Jan 7 2016')

Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (55555,'Building321','Jan 1 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (55555,'Safety104','Jan 4 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (55555,'ClientConflict202','Jan 7 2016')
Insert into StaffTraining(StaffID, TrainingID, CompletionDate)
values (55555,'Finishing123','Jan 7 2016')

Insert into Client (FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values ('Peggy', 'Sue','(780) 111-1111')
Insert into Client (FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values ('Maggie', 'May','(780) 222-2222')
Insert into Client (FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values ('Billy', 'Jean','(780) 111-1111')
Insert into Client (FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values ('Bobby', 'McGee','(780) 111-1111')
Insert into Client (FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values ('Tom', 'Dooly','(780) 111-1111')
Insert into Client (FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values ('Mary', 'Jane','(780) 111-1111')
Insert into Client (FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values ('Jimmy', 'Mack','(780) 111-1111')
Insert into Client (FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values ('Eleanor', 'Rigby','(780) 111-1111')

Insert Into Service (ServiceCode,Description,CostPerHour)
values ('Prime1','Priming',20)
Insert Into Service (ServiceCode,Description,CostPerHour)
values ('Painting1','Painting',20)
Insert Into Service (ServiceCode,Description,CostPerHour)
values ('Construction10','Basic Reconstruction',40)
Insert Into Service (ServiceCode,Description,CostPerHour)
values ('Construction20','Advanced Construction',60)
Insert Into Service (ServiceCode,Description,CostPerHour)
values ('Demolition','Demolition of Property',30)
Insert Into Service (ServiceCode,Description,CostPerHour)
values ('Sanding1','Surface Sanding',20)
Insert Into Service (ServiceCode,Description,CostPerHour)
values ('Cleaning1','Basic Cleaning',20)
Insert Into Service (ServiceCode,Description,CostPerHour)
values ('Garbage1','Removal of Graffit Refuse',25)




Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('Jan 1 2016','12345 Anywhere Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3D 1S5',120,26,126,11111,1)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (1,'Prime1','Prime fence beside the house',3,20,60)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes,hours, ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (1,'Painting1','Prime fence beside the house',3,20,60)

Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('Jan 2 2016','12345 First Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3A 1A5',160,8,168,11111,1)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (2,'Sanding1','Sand the wall',5,20,100)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (2,'Painting1','Paint the wall',3,20,60)

Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('Jan 3 2016','12345 Second Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3B 1B5',20,1,21,11111,1)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (3,'Painting1','Paint the door',1,20,20)

Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('Jan 3 2016','12345 Third Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3C 1C5',40,2,42,22222,2)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (4,'Cleaning1','Clean the wall',2,20,40)


Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('Jan 4 2016','12345 Fourth Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3D 1D5',80,4,84,22222,2)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (5,'Cleaning1','Clean the fence',4,20,80)


Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('February 5 2016','12345 Fifth Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3E 1E5',40,2,42,11111,3)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (6,'Painting1','Paint the sign',2,20,40)


Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('Jan 6 2016','12345 Sixth Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3F 1F5',60,3,63,33333,5)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (7,'Demolition','Take down the sign',2,30,60)


Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('Jan 7 2016','12345 Seventh Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3G 1G5',110,5.5,115.5,33333,1)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (8,'Demolition','Clean the wall',2,30,60)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (8,'Garbage1','Clean the wall',2,25,50)

Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('February 8 2016','12345 Eighth Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3H 1H5',40,2,42,44444,6)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (9,'Sanding1','Sand the blue fence',2,20,40)


Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('February 27 2016','12345 Ninth Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3I 1I5',20,1,21,44444,7)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (10,'Sanding1','Sand the table',1,20,20)


Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('February 28 2016','12345 Tenth Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3J 1J5',200,10,210,55555,8)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (11,'Construction10','Rebiuld Table',5,40,200)


Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('March 1 2016','12345 Eleventh Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3K 1K5',600,30,630,55555,3)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (12,'Construction20','Build new shed',10,60,600)


Insert into Job (Date, Address, City,Province,PostalCode,SubTotal,GST,Total,StaffID,ClientID)
values ('March 3 2016','12345 Twelth Street','Edmonton', 'AB','T3L 1L5',120,6,126,11111,8)
Insert Into JobService (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, Hours,ActualCostPerHour, extcost)
values (13,'Cleaning1','Clean the whole house!',12,10,120)


Insert Into SupplyCategory (SupplyCategoryCode, Description, StorageRoom)
values ('P5','5 Gallon Paint Products','A101')
Insert Into SupplyCategory (SupplyCategoryCode, Description, StorageRoom)
values ('P10','10 Gallon Paint Products','A101')
Insert Into SupplyCategory (SupplyCategoryCode, Description, StorageRoom)
values ('P20','20 Gallon Paint Products','A105')
Insert Into SupplyCategory (SupplyCategoryCode, Description, StorageRoom)
values ('S101','Sanding Supplies','S101')
Insert Into SupplyCategory (SupplyCategoryCode, Description, StorageRoom)
values ('B123','Demolition Equipment','DM212')
Insert Into SupplyCategory (SupplyCategoryCode, Description, StorageRoom)
values ('CL10','All Cleaning Supplies','B232')
Insert Into SupplyCategory (SupplyCategoryCode, Description, StorageRoom)
values ('B100','Building and Construction Materials','B202')
Insert Into SupplyCategory (SupplyCategoryCode, Description, StorageRoom)
values ('PR100','Primers','A211')
Insert Into SupplyCategory (SupplyCategoryCode, Description, StorageRoom)
values ('W100','Water','W211')


Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('PR104','Grey Primer','PR100')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('RP5','5 Gallon RedPaint','P5')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('BP10','10 Gallon Blue Paint','P10')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('GP20','20 Gallon Green Paint','P20')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('SP10','Sanding Paper','S101')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('PR105','White Primer','PR100')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('PR106','Black Primer','PR100')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('D100','Large Hammer','B123')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('DS100','Drywall Saw','B123')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('L100','Ladder','B100')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('N100','Nails','B100')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('C100','Soap','CL10')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('S100','Sponge','CL10')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('B100','Wire Brush','CL10')
Insert Into Supply (SupplyCode,Description, SupplyCategoryCode)
values ('T100','Towels','CL10')


Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(1,'BP10',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(1,'PR104',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(2,'PR104',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(2,'SP10',4)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(3,'RP5',1)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(4,'C100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(4,'S100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(5,'C100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(5,'S100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(6,'RP5',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(7,'DS100',1)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(8,'D100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(9,'SP10',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(10,'SP10',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(11,'D100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(11,'N100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(12,'L100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(12,'D100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(12,'N100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(13,'C100',2)
Insert into JobSupply (JobNumber,SupplyCode,Quantity)
values(13,'S100',2)


--Write the following queries:
--a.    Select the first name, last name (as one column) and phone number from client with client id 4. (1 mark)
select FirstName + ' ' + LastName, phone from Client
where ClientID = 4 

--b.    For all clients, select the client first name, last name and the number of jobs they have. (3 marks)
select FirstName + ' ' + LastName, count(ClientID)'job amount' from Client
inner join Job
on job.ClientID = Client.ClientID
group by FirstName + ' ' + LastName

--c.    Select the average CostPerHour of the services.(1 mark)
Select AVG(CostPerHour) from Service 

--d.    Create a list of all the client and staff first names and last names in descending order by last name.(2 marks)
select FirstName + ' ' + LastName from Staff
UNION
select FirstName + ' ' + LastName from Client
Order by LastName DESC
--e.    Select the supply code and description for all the supplies that have been used on more than 2 jobs.(4 marks)
select Supply.SupplyCode,Description, count(JobNumber)'Amount of jobs used in' from Supply
inner join JobSupply
on Supply.SupplyCode = JobSupply.SupplyCode
group by Supply.SupplyCode
having JobNumber >2 

--f.    Select jobnumber, date, full address, sub, GST, total, staff name (one column), client name (one column) and phone number for job number 2. (3 marks)
select JobNumber,Date,Address,SubTotal,GST,Total,FirstName + ' ' + LastName 'Name',Phone from Job
inner join Staff
on Job.StaffID = Staff.StaffID
inner join Client
on Job.ClientID = Client.ClientID
group by FirstName + ' ' + LastName
having JobNumber = 2

--g.    Select all the supply descriptions whose category code starts with “P”.     (2 marks)
select Description from Supply
where SupplyCategoryCode like 'P%'

--h.    Select the supply code and description of the supplies that have never been used on a job.(2 marks)
select Supply.SupplyCode,Description, Count(JobNumber)from Supply
inner join JobSupply
on Supply.SupplyCode = JobSupply.SupplyCode
group by Supply.SupplyCode 
having Count(JobNumber) = 0 

--i.    Select the first name, last name of the staff member who has taken the most number of training courses. (4 marks)
Select FirstName + ' ' + Lastname 'StaffName', Max(TrainingID) from Staff
inner join StaffTraining
on staff.StaffID = StaffTraining.StaffID
group by FirstName + ' ' + Lastname

--j.    Hard work has its rewards! On the last day of each month the staff member who worked on the job with the highest total for that month wins a $25 Tim Hortons gift card! This query will be executed on the last day of each month. Select the first name and the last name (one column) of the staff member who won the gift card for the current month.(4 marks)
select FirstName + ' ' + LastName 'Staff Name', Max(Total)from Staff
inner join Job
on Staff.StaffID = Job.StaffID
having  Max(Total) = Datediff(m,0,(Getdate()))

--k.    How many supplies are there in each supply category? Select the supplycategorycode, description and the count.(3 marks)
select distinct SupplyCategoryCode, Description, count(*) from Supply

Update Service
SET CostPerHour = CostPerHour*1.1
where Description = 'Painting'

delete SupplyCategory
where Description = ' '


Select * from JobService
Select * from  Service
Select * from  JobSupply
Select * from  Supply
Select * from  SupplyCategory
Select * from  Job
Select * from  Client
Select * from  StaffTraining
Select * from  Training
Select * from  Staff
Select * from  StaffType
```

Comment: ***WHERE*** in all this SQL does the error occur? Which tables *can* you create, where does it bomb out??

Comment: it will not tell me, but i am assuming in the created tables

Comment: Ok so after a more detailed investigation I found that the `DEFAULT` constraint on Job table generates the error you are describing in your question. You should also declare the column name the constraint is for like that: 
    `Alter table job  

     Add constraint DF_Province  default 'AB' FOR Province`

Comment: thank you, i didnt even think to try that...i am just overwhelmed by my limit of time

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to delete tables at the top of the code? Shouldn't it be:

Drop JobService

Drop Service

Drop JobSupply

...

Comment: Although `delete` is correct syntactically, it only removes rows in the tables, not the table itself.

Comment: i thought that, but my prof did that so i left it .... i should have tried that... i will thought